# how to get facebook signed request with titanium framework

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, drupal-6, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am developing iphone app through titanium which is communicate with drupal 6 server through services module.

My requirement is when user logged in to facebook from mobile, it treat as authenticated user from server side for further facebook operation performed by server.

So I am trying to get signed request for logged in user from mobile, but I am not able to get signed request for logged in user.

I called following function to open facebook login popup,

```
Ti.Facebook.authorize();
```

following listener execute after facebook login,

```
Ti.Facebook.addEventListener('login', function(e) { }
```

May i know how to get signed request after successfully logged in to facebook from device??

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience in connecting to Facebook from Titanium, but installed one of their new example apps two days ago: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Example+Applications#ExampleApplications-ARti

This connects to FB, do not know in what way. You can download example code from GitHub, maybe you find it useful.